# Looking for help when using Mediawiki "recentchanges" syntax

Tags: mediawiki

I am having a hard time finding an example of what I am looking for. I am trying to show recent changes on one of my category pages using {{special:recentchanges/day=5,limit=10}}. I am part of a busy Wiki and am trying to limit the search to just a particular category or my watchlist.

I can see from the "Help:recent changes" page on the main MediaWiki website that it lists "namespace" as an integer but I cant seem to get it to work narrowing down to just a specific category in conjunction with the above line.

Long story short: I would just like to show recent changes to a specific category or my watchlist on my main category page. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Namespaces are unrelated to categories. You cannot filter recent changes by category. You can use `Special:RecentChangesLinked` instead which is similar.

Answer (score 0):

Tgr's answer is correct, copying here: Namespaces are unrelated to categories. You cannot filter [Special:RecentChanges](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Recent_changes) by category. You can use [Special:RecentChangesLinked](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Related_changes) instead which is similar.

For more, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Help:Tracking_changes